# showing pytest diff inside pytest.fail call

Tags: python, pytest

When pytest's `assert` fail, it shows a really nice diff between expected and actual data.

```
E       AssertionError: assert {'0', '1', '3', '8'} == {'0', '3', '5', '8'}
E         Extra items in the left set:
E         '1'
E         Extra items in the right set:
E         '5'
E         Use -v to get the full diff
```

I have a custom fixture which may fail the test if some external data do not match by using `pytest.fail(msg='..', pytrace=False)`. I'd like to show a nice diff like pytest at that moment. How to show pytest-style diff?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? I'm not sure I understand your use case. Do you have the differing items? When does `pytest.fail` happen - is this in your code, or in the external fixture? Maybe you can add some example code to show this.

Comment: It's tests for external data. Fixtures are loading files, and test compare them. I don't want to use assert, as bug is in the data (not a code), so I use `pytest.fail` function (which is mostly very good, except for lack of diffs). I would like to add nice diff into `pytest.fail` message but don't know how.

Comment: Why exactly is `assert external_data == expected_external_data` in the fixture is not possible?

Comment: assert in the fixture will print trace and point to the asserted line. Instead I'd like to complain that 'file1' is not the same as 'file2'. I use `pytest.fail` for this, but I want to add diff there.